# Open SSL X509 certificate fail due to "Unrecognized flag days365"

Tags: openssl

I am trying to generate an X509 certificate using open SSL the command I am using is:

```
root@broker1:/etc/mosquitto/quectel# openssl req -new -x509 -days365 -key mosq-ca.key -out mosq-ca.crt
```

the response is:

```
req: Unrecognized flag days365
req: Use -help for summary.
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That should be one argument, the flag `-days`, and a _separate_ argument, the value `365`, **with a space between**.  As the help messages shows, if you follow the instruction it gives, or the man page, if you look at it as you should. And this isn't programming or development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this to be the correct format for generating an X509 certificate named mosq-ca.crt using the keyfile mosq-ca.key

```
openssl req -x509 -new -key mosq-ca.key -days 365 -out mosq-ca.crt
```